# Rails - Simple form, not saving the input to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, simple-form-for

I'm not sure why but I cannot save my form input to the database, and I couldn't find any answer so far :), but it works for creating the posts using the console.

```
  Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-23 14:04:32 +0300
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"B19yVi1jHtg7068SKFbI3tj28THNdfgGYwUSN+e79Vt/o0ivDUl0D4i71PuLKlZf1wxnEJMVnp+GmH/HcxE6cQ==", "post"=>{"category_id"=>"2", "title"=>"asfaf", "content"=>"asfkja", "photo_cache"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
Unpermitted parameter: :photo_cache
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  Category Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
```

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a category" }) %><br>
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Type the post title here" %><br>
  <%= f.label :content %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Type the post text here" %><br>
  <%= f.input :photo %>
  <%= f.input :photo_cache, as: :hidden %><br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  authorize @post
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  authorize @post
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: "The post was created!"
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def post_params 
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :category_id, :photo, :user_id)
end
```

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, :content, :category_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end
```

Comment: Can you check the logfile, and show us: what is posted to the controller (`params`), and possibly the error? Do you have any validations in your `Post` model?

Comment: Edited the post and added what's logged in the console and my validations :)

Comment: Can you provide the error(s) in `@post.errors.details`? You can do this by placing a `byebug` in your `else` statement and use the interactive debugger (use the command `c` to continue). Or output `@post.errors.details.to_s` in your `app/views/posts/new` view.

Comment: `pry(#<PostsController>)> @post.errors.details
=> {:category_id=>[{:error=>:blank}], :category=>[{:error=>:blank}], :user=>[{:error=>:blank}]}` apprently it's rolling back because it finds no category and no user?

Comment: using `@post.errors.details.to_s` in the view I'm getting `{:user=>[{:error=>:blank}]} ` so basically it finds no user? I'm using Devise for auth, in console current_user returns nil

Answer (score 2):

Console output points the reason - you pass `photo_cache` parameter while have not permitted it:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :photo_cache
```

So, just add `:photo_cache` to `permit` list:

```
params.require(:post).permit(..., :photo_cache)
```

**UPDATE**: If `Post` model belongs to `User`, it should have *foreign key* constraint and you *must* pass `user_id` parameter to `Post.create`.
In real apps something like `Devise` is used for authentication and controller looks like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController    
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    post = current_user.posts.create!(create_params)
    # post = Post.new(create_params.merge(user: current_user))
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Already tried adding this, still doesn't work, the problem is that the user is not being passed as a parameter so it cannot create it, probably a Devise problem

Comment: What do you mean "the user is not being passed as a parameter" @Lamperoyge? Pavel's answer will be an issue you'll need to address somewhere - it sounds like you might have an additional problem on top of this? Perhaps updating the user association to be optional, using: `belongs_to :user, optional: true`?

Comment: Yes, my initial post addressed your first issue, while you have many of them. Updated post with `user` passing. And it is not "Devise problem" definitely. If you have your `Post` connected to `User`, you **must** fill out `user_id`

Answer (score 0):

Basically what helped is changing the create method

```
def create
 @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
 authorize @post
 if @post.save
  redirect_to @post, notice: "The post was created!"
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end
```